# store input value which is in loop with javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, debugging

I have a column input field in `<td>` which is in the loop due to this each `Row` has `input` field I got a `javascript` from which it storing `local storage` for `input` field but the issue is this javascript is working only for one `input` For Example :

I have five rows and due to loop `input` field generated for 5 rows automatically

What I am looking for is to store different values for each row..due to this script its not implementing for each row individually

Code

```
<input type="text" id="txt_1" onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("txt_1").value = getSavedValue("txt_1");    // set the value to this input
        document.getElementById("txt_2").value = getSavedValue("txt_2");   // set the value to this input
        /* Here you can add more inputs to set value. if it's saved */

        //Save the value function - save it to localStorage as (ID, VALUE)
        function saveValue(e){
            var id = e.id;  // get the sender's id to save it . 
            var val = e.value; // get the value. 
            localStorage.setItem(id, val);// Every time user writing something, the localStorage's value will override . 
        }

        //get the saved value function - return the value of "v" from localStorage. 
        function getSavedValue  (v){
            if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
                return "";// You can change this to your defualt value. 
            }
            return localStorage.getItem(v);
        }
</script>
```

Image Showing

[image]

COde

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="input-group">
<thead ><tr >
 <th class="text-right"><?php echo "Contact No."; ?></th>
  <th><?php echo "Followup 1 Date"; ?>
    </th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
      if (empty($enquiry_list)) {
       ?>
       <?php
        } else {
        foreach ($enquiry_list as $key => $value) {
         $current_date = date("d/m/Y");
         $next_date = $value["next_date"];
         if (empty($next_date)) { $next_date = $value["follow_up_date"];
          }if ($next_date < $current_date) {                                      
          $class = "class='danger'";} else {
           $class = ""; } ?>
           <td class="mailbox-name"><?php echo $value['contact']; ?> </td>
   <td class="mailbox-name" >
    <div  style="width:200px" style="height:200px" >
     <input id="txt_<?= $row[id] ?>" onkeyup='saveValue(this);' 
      autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control"   /></div></td>
      </tr> </tr>
      <?php }}?> </tbody> </table>
```

Comment: So you have 5 rows with the same ids and you wonder why it does not work?

Comment: rows are fetching from MySQL and after implement input field it created input field for each row for example if I have 2 entries in mysql input field created for each

Comment: Your code doesn't explain what you want. In your question you talk about loop, I see none. And this refers to what for you to try e.id and e.value?

Comment: So what the question really is is how can you do this without hard coding each input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var inputGroup = document.getElementById('input-group');
var inputs = inputGroup.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
{
 var id = inputs[i].getAttribute('id');
 inputs[i].value = getSavedValue(id);
} 
 
//Save the value function - save it to localStorage as (ID, VALUE)
function saveValue(e){
    var id = e.id;  // get the sender's id to save it . 
    var val = e.value; // get the value. 
    localStorage.setItem(id, val);// Every time user writing something, the localStorage's value will override . 
}

//get the saved value function - return the value of "v" from localStorage. 
function getSavedValue  (v){
    if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
        return "";// You can change this to your defualt value. 
    }
    return localStorage.getItem(v);
}
```

```html
<table id="input-group">
  <tr>
   <th>Text 1</th>
   <th><input type="text" id="txt_1" onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/> </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Text 2</th>
   <th><input type="text" id="txt_2" onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/> </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Text 3</th>
   <th><input type="text" id="txt_3" onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/> </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Text 4</th>
   <th><input type="text" id="txt_4" onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/> </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Text 5</th>
   <th><input type="text" id="txt_5" onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/> </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i know the issue due to loop in <td> for next row data input field id become same because other <td> is fetching from MYSQL is there any way is to create ID autoamticaly once the input is used in loop

Comment: I have added the table if you need dynamic id then you can set **id="txt_<?= $row[id]  ?>"**. that will automatically assigned unique id in the input.

Comment: <input type="text" id="txt_<?= $row[id] ?>" onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/> </th> like this with given java script

Comment: Yes. try this :)

Comment: input value not storing in it

Comment: i added the image in my question

Comment: when the input field created for for next row its not storing the value in it only storing for one input and echo in all

Comment: Oops, you did not add the loop of the data. Please add then I will show you the use of the input PHP condition. It's not working due to id issue

Comment: Use **<?= $key ?>** instead of **<?= row[id] ?>** in the input field

Comment: You don't need to create **$loop=1;** variable. Just use **<?= $key ?>** instead of **<?= row[id] ?>** in the input field

Comment: Thanks, Bro for your help (Charan Sparsh Prabhu) You Save my Night... with this can I create a loop for another column <td> like for follow-up remarks

Comment: i hope the data will not remove after cleared the cached

Comment: what if I have more input columns like this in the same loop does it work for individually for all

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to pass the event listener to the function that you have implemented, so i've solved it adding the events on the `js` file.
So instead of this:

```
<input type="text" id="txt_1" onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/>
```

You need to add the event on the js:

```
<input type="text" id="txt_1"/> 
<input type="text" id="txt_2"/> 

document.getElementById("txt_1").onkeyup = saveValue;
document.getElementById("txt_2").onkeyup = saveValue;
```

After this you need to access the id and the value from the `event.target` like this:

```
function saveValue(e) {
  var id = e.target.id; // get the sender's id to save it .
  var val = e.target.value; // get the value.
  localStorage.setItem(id, val); // Every time user writing something, the localStorage's value will override .
}
```

Look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-smoke-kjhkn) and see if it helps you out

Comment: rows are fetching from MySQL and after implement input field it created input field for each row for example if I have 2 entries in mysql input field created for each the problem is the value is storing in only one input

Answer (score 0):

Html is not reliable. You can use pure javascript code for cleaner way. Here is the working sample. Slackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xycijp

```js
function saveValue({ target }, index) {
  localStorage.setItem(target.id, target.value); // Every time user writing
  // OR
  localStorage.setItem("target.id"+index, target.value); // Every time user writing something, the localStorage's value will override .
}

//get the saved value function - return the value of "v" from localStorage.
function getSavedValue(v) {
  if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
    return ""; // You can change this to your defualt value.
  }
  return localStorage.getItem(v);
}
document.querySelectorAll(".textField").forEach((elm, index) => {
  elm.addEventListener("input", (e) => saveValue(e, index), false);
});

// Can ignore
window.saveValue = saveValue;
window.getSavedValue = getSavedValue;
```

```html
<input class='textField' type="text" id="txt_1" /> 
<input class='textField' type="text" id="txt_2" />
```